How do i Migrate a Prismic Website to Worpress ? And resources related to this
I am stuck with a problem, I am asked to migrate a website from Prismic to WordPress. I have tried almost all I can think of but firstly I couldn't find a suitable resource over the internet outlining migration from or into the Prismic. Secondly, the structure of exported data is very unfamiliar it is hard to wrap my head around.
I have tried to understand the exported data structure to wrap my head around it but it was very difficult to grasp. Can anyone suggest anything helpful?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The process will require significant work because the two CMS platforms are fundamentally different in how they manage content, structure, and presentation
prismic is a headless cms, wordpress is a traditional cms both front-end and back-end built together
